# Operador de coma en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy estudiando el uso de la coma para separar variables:

```
var suma = 10, iterador;
```

No entiendo por qué obtengo error cuando hago:

```
var resultado = contador = 20, contador += 5;
```

Si entendí bien se evalúa la expresión de izquierda a derecha, con lo que cuando intento incrementar la variable contador ya debería estar declarada e inicializada con valor de 20.
Gracias

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La sintaxis de la sentencia `var` no admite el operador `+=`.

Fíjate que la sintaxis de `var` es la siguiente:

> var nombreDeVariable1 [= valor1] [, nombreDeVariable2 [= valor2] ... [, nombreDeVariableN [=valorN]]];

El operador `+=` no aparece en su definición.

Lo normal es usar `var` para inicializar una variable y opcionalmente darle un valor.

Si le vas a dar un segundo valor lo normal es hacerlo en otra sentencia:

```
var contador = 20;
contador += 5;
```

EDIT: Aunque efectivamente, la sintaxis de `var` no permite el operador `+=`, la sintaxis de una expresión (lo que iría en valor1, valor2, ..., valorN) si que lo permite; como bien apunta String Manolo en su otra respuesta, por lo que si que se podría hacer esto:

```
var resultado = contador = 20, contador = (contador += 5);
```

o incluso

```
var resultado = contador = 20, contador = contador + 5;
```

Ahora lo que habría que preguntarse, es, ¿para qué se quiere hacer dos asignaciones diferentes sobre la misma variable en una única sentencia, en lugar de hacer una única asignación con valor 25 a contador?. Lo normal sería inicializar la variable una vez, y después alterar su valor en sentencias sucesivas.

Más info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas.
Encontré una descripción del operador coma en esta url:
https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/6524-the-confusing-comma-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 3):

Sí puedes hacerlo.

```
var resultado = contador = 20, a = (contador += 5)
```

El problema es que la sintaxis no se admite porque omites el variable=

Véase por ejemplo:

```
var uno = 1, a = "a", verdad = true;
```

Si metes coma en var se espera el formato de identificador = valor.

Como valor puede ser una expresión, puedes hacer la suma, una llamada a una función, o lo que quieras que deje ahí un algo que sea válido para asignarle al identificador.

Comment: Bien visto, he modificado mi respuesta para añadir esta información.